# xltabular: prevent or suggest pagebreak

Tags: xltabular

Does xltabular support \nopagebreak or \pagebreak? I tried to add it to prevent pagebreak between lines 11 and 12 but it did not work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}

\title{xltabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\  \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 11 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 12 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\  \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline

\end{xltabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: `\\*` prevent tale break table after this row. Syntax are the same as at `longtable` package.

Comment: It is not working if I have cline

Comment: Indeed. I guess that you like lines 11 and 12 to keep together. In this case insert `\pagebreak` before line 11.

Comment: I produce this file automatically. I can't know when to use `\pagebreak`. And the `\pagebreak[3]` is not working too.

Comment: Than I can't help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative: with version 2021M (2021-08-01) of `tabularray` package, you can use `\\*`, `\nopagebreak` and `\pagebreak` for both `\hline` and `\cline` in `longtblr` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a6paper,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Tabular},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:abcd},
]{
  colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.9\linewidth,
  rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1
}
\hline
 Head & Head & Head \\
\hline                               
 Head & Head & Head \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\\nopagebreak
\cline{2-3}
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\*
\cline{2-3}
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\cline{2-3}\pagebreak
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Foot & Foot & Foot \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `\nobreak` to `\cline` so it never breaks after a cline

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\makeatletter
\def\@cline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\nobreak\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatother
\title{xltabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\  \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 11 & & \\* \cline{2-3}
Line 12 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\ \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\  \cline{2-3} 
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline
Line 1 & & \\
Line 2 & & \\ \hline

\end{xltabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found two simple options to apply to the MWE. None modifies the table file.

(1) add a very small vertical space to the caption line to encourage an earlier break. `\vspace*{2pt}` will do.

(2) expand the cells by an unnoticeable amount, for example by adding `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.005}` before `\begin{xltabular}`, for a full first-page table.

[image: b]

```
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \vspace*{2pt}\\
```

or

```
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.005}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
...
\end{xltabular}}
```